# "scrolling is allowed even after the scrollpolicies are off"

Tags: apache-flex

i made both the scrollpolicies (horizontal and vertical scrollpolicy) to "off", but if i scroll the mouse the content was scrolling.

how to avoid this behaviour?

the sample code is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns="*" creationComplete="init()">
<s:HGroup id="hgroup" chromeColor="110011"> 
    <s:Scroller width="300" height="100" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
    <s:Group >
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout />
        </s:layout>
        <s:Button label="Button 1" />
        <s:Button label="Button 2" />
        <s:Button label="Button 3" />
        <s:Button label="Button 4" />
        <s:Button label="Button 5" />
        <s:Button label="Button 6" />
        <s:Button label="Button 7" />
    </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
</s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```

if you just click the hgroup and scroll,then the contents are scrolling. now i want to aoid this behaviour.please verify and post your suggestions and comments.

please note that i haven't use any builder,i run the code in command prompt only.
please post your answers.

Comment: on what component? some code example?

Comment: thanks a lot Nevena, here i give you the code

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's some inline code which modified the scrollpolicy
Post your code, maybe it could be useful to look for the error

Comment: thanks for your reply, but there was no modification made on the scroll policies. even i tried by simple coding,i have got the same behaviour.i am using flex 4.0 sdk.pls tell me is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: dear Franky ,i have added the sample code. please verify and suggest me to avoid that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Buddy.....you kept off on scroll policies...then better take of the horizontal & vertical scroll policies and keep width="100%".....

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
```

orelse use

```
 <s:Scroller horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" verticalScrollPolicy="auto">
```

Comment: is tat works fine and good....its coz u may use vbox, canvas in ur application....it suits thier height and width and it does not  allow another components to use in their width and height....so the better way to take those unwanted scroll policy and left their access to its own behaviour....or auto...tats it! cya!

Comment: yeah it is working well, but we didn't have this issue in flex 3 , then why does flex 4 make this issue?.

Comment: In Flex 3, the layout of components and containers are defined inside individual controls. Halo components which include List, TileList, and HorizontalList are used. In Flex 4, the layout has been decoupled from components. Spark components are used in Flex 4 which includes Application, List, ButtonBar, and Panel  A major pain point which almost everyone developing Flex 3 applications has encountered is poor compiler performance. Whereas in Flex 4 , there is improved compiler performance. 25% improvement would be reached without significant restructuring.